# Confusion with number of commuting permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Find the number of permutations in $S_6$ which commute with $\sigma = (1 \ 2 \  3) (4 \ 5)$

This was my attempt:

A permutation $\tau \in S_6$ commutes with $\sigma \iff \sigma =\tau^{-1} \sigma \tau = (\tau(1) \ \tau(2) \ \tau(3))  ( \tau (4) \ \tau(5))$.

Using the theorm on the uniqueness of decomposition to cycles we want the following to hold:
$$ (\tau(1) \ \tau(2) \ \tau(3)) = (1 \ 2 \  3)$$
$$ ( \tau (4) \ \tau(5)) = (4 \ 5)$$

Now comes my confusion:

The way I see it the only valid values for $ (\tau(1) \ \tau(2) \ \tau(3))$ are $(1 \ 2 \ 3), (3 \ 1 \ 2), (2 \ 3 \ 1)$ since these are all the ways to write the same cycle. and similarly $(4 \ 5), (5 \ 4)$. so we should have $3*2=6$ commuting permutations in total.

However, when I check manually I find that $ (\tau(1) \ \tau(2) \ \tau(3)) = (1 \ 3 \ 2)$ also commutes:

$$ \sigma \tau = (1 \ 2 \  3) (4 \ 5) (1 \ 3 \ 2) (4 \ 5) =  (1 \ 2 \  3) (1 \ 3 \ 2) = I = (1 \ 3 \ 2)(1 \ 2 \ 3) = (1 \ 3 \  2) (4 \ 5) (1 \ 2 \ 3) (4 \ 5) = \tau \sigma$$

Can someone please explain my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tau=(1\ 3\ 2)$ does indeed commute with $\sigma$, and $(\tau(1)\ \tau(2)\ \tau(3))=(3\ 1\ 2)$ which is one of your valid values, so there is no problem. The mistake is that you've treated the statements "$(\tau(1)\ \tau(2)\ \tau(3))=(a\ b\ c)$" and "$\tau=(a\ b\ c)$" as the same, which they aren't.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. From the statement (τ(1) τ(2) τ(3))=(1 2 3) we get the 3 solutions:
τ=(1)(2)(3), 
τ=(1 3 2),
τ =(2 3 1).

Does that seem correct?

Comment: in τ=(1)(2)(3) I mean τ=Identity to be clear